# Error with FusionCharts Server-side export in ASP.NET

Tags: fusioncharts

I am trying to use FusionCharts ASP.NET Server side export handler and whenever I try to invoke, am getting Response Code 500 with the message stating "Can not parse the CSS file".

I need to get this error resolve to enable export via Server side. Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been fixed internally and you can receive it in the upcoming release of FusionCharts.